# kohana error when model instantiation

Tags: php, model, kohana, instantiation

Every time I try to instantiate a certain model and use it, like for example:

```
$categories  = Model::factory('category')->by_sale($id)->find_all();
```

I get a weird error. If i have i bootstrap in kohana::init set 'errors' => TRUE,the error is: `Could not execute Model_Category::__construct()` else i get only a warning `Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /application/classes/model.php on line 42`

meaning here:

```
private function _get_real_property_name($property)
{
    if (isset($this->_belongs_to[$property]) OR
        isset($this->_has_one[$property]) OR
        isset($this->_has_many[$property]))
    return $property;

    $column_prefix   = $this->_table_name . '_';
    $property_prefix = substr($property, 0, strlen($column_prefix));

    if ($property_prefix != $column_prefix)
    {
        $prefixed_property = $column_prefix . $property;

        if (in_array($prefixed_property, array_keys($this->table_columns())))
        {
            return $prefixed_property;
        }
    }

    return $property;
}
```

The category model looks like this:

```
class Model_Category extends Model {
    /**
     * @see  ORM::_table_name
     *
     * @var  array
     */
    protected $_table_name = 'category';

    /**
     * @see  ORM::_primary_key
     *
     * @var  array
     */
    protected $_primary_key = 'category_id';

    /**
     * @see  ORM::_belongs_to
     *
     * @var  array
     */
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'parent' => array('model' => 'category', 'foreign_key' => 'category_category'),
        'sale' => array('foreign_key' => 'category_sale')
    );

    /**
     * @see  ORM::_has_many
     *
     * @var  array
     */
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'products' => array('model' => 'product', 'foreign_key' => 'product_category')
    );

    /**
     * Adds the 'top_level' condition to the query
     *
     * @return  Model_Sale
     */
    public function top_level()
    {
        return $this->where('category_category', '=', 0);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the 'by_sale' condition to the query
     *
     * @return  Model_Sale
     */
    public function by_sale($sale_id)
    {
        return $this->where('category_sale', '=', $sale_id);
    }

    public function __get($property)
    {
        if ($property == 'siblings')
        {
            return $this->where('category_sale', '=', $this->sale->id)
                ->where('category_category', '=', $this->category_category);
        }

        if ($property == 'children')
        {
            return $this->where('category_category', '=', $this->pk());
        }
        return parent::__get($property);
    }
} // End Model_Category
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your model must extends ORM class instead of Model

Comment: trid like this too, but doesn;t work. i extend the model class because i created a class that extends the orm class. and works for any other models.

Comment: And you name this class `Model` (`extends ORM`)? Dont use system class names or your custom classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recognize the `$this->table_columns()`. When looking at http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Model I don't see it there either.

Have you added this method to the Model class yourself? I'm guessing it's not returning the proper type.

Comment: yes i added myself. in order to call the models'objects more easily (short terms instead of long ones).

Comment: also, it works perfectly on all the other models. i have this problem only here,in this case. and it really confuses me.

Comment: could you paste your table_columns() method ?

Comment: it's a ORM propery:  protected static $_properties = array
 (
  'object_name', 'object_plural', 'loaded', 'saved', // Object
  'primary_key', 'primary_val', 'table_name', 'table_columns', // Table
  'has_one', 'belongs_to', 'has_many', 'has_many_through', 'load_with', // Relationships
  'validate', 'rules', 'callbacks', 'filters', 'labels' // Validation
 );

Comment: table_columns() is a property of the ORM module. in the class containing the method _get_real_property_name($property) i actually extend the orm class

Comment: wait. Why do you use brackets if it's a variable then ?

Comment: nope it is not a variable. now i see it is a method also, but i can't find it.

Comment: does your Model class extend the ORM class or Kohana_Model ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Kohana, but it is quite resembling with Codeigniter. You can try this in your model that extends model class:

function __construct(){
        parent::Model();
    }
(eventually pass the parameters that you have)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `$this->table_columns()` by `$this->table_columns` (in `_get_real_property_name()`) because `table_columns` seems to be a variable, not a method :3

Comment: doesnt work. it seems that it is also a method, but i cant figure out where it is right now.i have inherited a code from someone else, and i am a little puzzled. the thing is that he problem appears only at the category model. alll the other models work perfect, in the same scenario.

Comment: $_table_columns is a private variable in Kohana_ORM, it can be accessed using ->table_columns() because of the implementation of the __call magic method

Comment: oh my bad. As you know I don't use Kohana's ORM. I should have checked first :D